# yup validation can not validate all fields

Tags: javascript, typescript, yup

I want to validate a form using yup, the problem is that when I want to loop the errors thrown by yup, I find out that the last filed that I enter is not valid:

```
    const schema = yup.object().shape({
        age: yup.number().required("age is required"),
        name: yup.string().required("name is required"),
        email : yup.string().required("email is required"),
    });
    
    try{
        schema.validateSync({form}, {abortEarly: false})
    }catch(e:any){
        let err = {
            age : '',
            name : '',
            email : '',
        }
        
        e.inner.forEach(error => {
            err[error.path] = error.message
        })
    }
    
    console.log(err)
```

When I fill the name and age firstly, then I will get error say email is not valid even I fill it:

```
let form = {
   age : '32', // filled first
   name : 'mike',  // filled second
   email : 'mike@dev.com',  // filled last
}
```

I got :

```
err = {
   age : '',
   name : '',
   email : 'email is required',
}
```

same thing with the name if I fill age and email, generally last field it will not be validated, any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line: `schema.validateSync({form}, {abortEarly: false})`
should be `schema.validateSync({...form}, {abortEarly: false})` or
`schema.validateSync(form, {abortEarly: false})`.

```
schema.validateSync({form}) will validate the object {form: form} not 
    {
       age : '32', 
       name : 'mike', 
       email : 'mike@dev.com',
    }
```

Comment: I also set up [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-7wtzfk?file=index.js) stackblitz example so you can check it out.